# Proving that a formula is not a WFF

Tags: logic, computer-science, propositional-calculus

So we know that the basic properties of a well formed formula is one where the number of left and right brackets are equal, every initial proper segment is contains more left brackets than right brackets and that the WFF is either an atomic formula or starts with a left bracket. But I'm having trouble proving that this formula is not a WFF:

$$(((p \rightarrow q)) \wedge p)$$

Comment: It is a WFF. What is your problem with it?

Comment: wouldn't $$((p \rightarrow q))$$ violate something because we essentially have more brackets than needed? How can I come up with a construction sequence to get that?

Comment: You seem to be referring to another definition of WFF that bans extraneous brackets. I think you need to give some more context to your question.

Comment: @RobArthan The definitions of WFF I've seen before *do* ban extraneous brackets, FWIW.

Comment: The OP's list of properties of a WFF do allow extraneous brackets. Typical definitions in logic texts are as you say, but nonetheless require the brackets in  $(p \land q)$, which are obviously extraneous.

Comment: @RobArthan The parentheses in (p$\land$q) are necessary according to the inductive definition of a well-formed formula.  It's often a meta-theorem that every well-formed which is not a variable with a binary connective has parentheses in it, or even every well-formed formula which is not a variable has parentheses in it.

Answer (score 1):

One way of defining a well-formed formula goes that it comes as possible to construct a sequence of symbols where every step $\alpha$ gets built up according to the following :

1. $\alpha$ is a propositional variable.
2. $\alpha$ got obtained from a well-formed formula $\beta$ by prefixing a '$\lnot$' to $\beta$.
3. $\alpha$ got obtained from two well-formed formulas '$\beta$' and '$\gamma$' such that it has the following form ($\beta$$\land$$\gamma$).
4. $\alpha$ got obtained from two well-formed formulas '$\beta$' and '$\gamma$' such that if has the following form ($\beta$$\rightarrow$$\gamma$).

(((p→q))∧p) can't get obtained that way, since there is no sequence of well-formed formulas that yields (((p→q))∧p) as a well-formed formula.

Also, sometimes the author using the term 'well-formed formula' writes something like:

"Nothing else is a well-formed formula."

after writing the other parts of the inductive definition of a well-formed formula.

(((p→q))∧p) falls into that nothing else category, as follows from the fact that the left conjunct ((p→q)) can't get constructed, since (p$\rightarrow$q) has to exist in some construction sequence first, and there is no rule which allows one to add more parentheses.

In summary:

A sequence of symbols is a well-formed formula on the condition that it can get constructed according to the formation rules.  If a sequence of symbols can't get constructed according to the formation rules, it's not a well-formed formula.

Edit: One might point out that if a well-formed formula is well-formed in some infix language, then it has some unique counterpart in a prefix (or postfix) language and conversely.  But, were it the case that ((p$\rightarrow$q)) were well-formed, then $\rightarrow$pq (or pq$\rightarrow$) wouldn't have a unique infix language counterpart for the infix language at hand, since presumably (p$\rightarrow$q) and ((p$\rightarrow$q)) have the same meaning.